# Is it true that $\mu(f^{-n}(B) \triangle B) = 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability space and let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and such that $\mu(f^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Assume that the set $B \in \mathcal{F}$ is such that
$$
\mu (f^{-1}(B) \triangle B) = 0,
$$
where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference, i.e. $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

> Is it true that
> $$
> \mu(f^{-n}(B) \triangle B) = 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \tag{1}
> $$
> where $f^{-n}(B)$ denotes the preimage of $B$ w.r.t. the $n$'th application of $f$.

It is easy to see that
$$
0 = \mu (f^{-1}(B) \triangle B) = \mu (f^{-1}(f^{-1}(B) \triangle B)) = \mu (f^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)) \triangle f^{-1}(B)) = \mu (f^{-2}(B) \triangle f^{-1}(B)) = \mu (f^{-(n+1)}(B) \triangle f^{-n}(B)) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
But what can be said about $(1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\mu\left(A\Delta B\right)=\int_\Omega\lvert \mathbf{1}_A-\mathbf{1}_B\rvert d\mu$ hence
$$
\mu\left(f^{-n}(B)\Delta B\right)\leqslant\sum_{j=1}^n
\int_\Omega \lvert \mathbf{1}_{f^{-j}(B)}-\mathbf{1}_{f^{-j+1}(B)}\rvert d\mu
\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\mu\left(f^{-j}(B)\Delta f^{-j+1}(B)\right) $$
which is zero by your observation.